# Service Fabric - binding similar to IIS

Tags: asp.net, azure-service-fabric

I am new to Service Fabric and I was wondering if I can achieve the following.

In IIS I would use binding to achieve the following:

ex.

```
sub1.mydomain.com.au:80 --> MyApp1 (This would be an ASP.NET Web Site or Web API)
sub2.mydomain.com.au:80 --> MyApp2 (This would be another ASP.NET Web Site or Web API)
```

How do you do this in Service Fabric

I have 2 web sites running as services in Service Fabric:

```
WebService1 port: 8666 (Asp.Net Core Web App)
WebService2 port: 8777 (Asp.Net Core Web API)
```

Now, from the load balancer I can configure port 80 to bind to backend port 8666, but how can I configure port 80 (with sub domain "sub2") to backend port 8777?

Is it even possible, or should I be using something else to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [reverse proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy) functionality.
It takes the ServiceInstanceName as a variable.

> Instead of configuring individual service's ports in the azure load
>   balancer, just the SF Reverse proxy port can be configured in the
>   Azure Load Balancer. This allows clients outside the cluster to reach
>   services inside the cluster via the reverse proxy without additional
>   configuration.

Comment: Thanks for that. Sorry, I am really new to this concept. From what I understand I can access the 2nd service (the one running on Port 8777) after configuring the reverse proxy through: http://sub1.mydomain.com.au:19008/MyApp/MyService/api/users, correct? Saying that, Is it possible to configure the reverse proxy on port 80 so I can access the resource through: http://sub1.mydomain.com.au/MyApp/MyService/api/users ?

Comment: If you're running on an (Azure) cluster with a load balancer, you can add a load balancing rule that maps incoming port 80 to backend port 19008. That's easiest.

Comment: Yes I am, thanks. Going back to my original question, I am having second thoughts if this actually solves my problem. Lets say I have two front end asp.net core websites (not apis) running in the cluster. Will the user have to go to http://mydomain/myapp/site1 and http://mydomain/myapp/site2 to access the sites? I was hoping to have the user go to http://site1.mydomain and http://site2.mydomain to access front end websites.(similar to what I do in IIS)

Comment: I think you can do that by adding two public IP addresses to your Load Balancer, each with their own DNS config.

Comment: I will try that. Do you know of any documents explaining how to do that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-multivip-overview

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it go.